# Abstract class in Java - creating objects

Tags: java, oop, object, abstract-class

I'm writing a code in Java using abstract classes for the first time and I have a problem. I have a list (array) of users, each of them is an object of userClass. I have created an abstract class 'account' and 2 classes which extends it 'basicAccount' and 'premiumAccount' and I would like to create basic or premium account for every user depending on an input. My problem is that I don't know how to implement userClass, so it would create object of basic or premium class depending on a string 'accountType' Example:

```
public class userClass {
private String email;
private String accountType;
private account account;

public userClass(String email, String accountType){
    this.setEmail(email);
    this.setAccountType(accountType);

    if(accountType.equals("Basic")){
        basicAccount account = new basicAccount();
    }
    else if(accountType.equals("Premium")){
        premiumAccount account = new premiumAccount();
    }
}
```

Could you please help me? Can I put those if's in userClass method?

Comment: Actually your code is mostly correct. You just need to remove account classes(premiumAccount and basicAccount) in front of 'account' variables. Just initilaze them as related sub-class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very important concept in Object-oriented Programming is *polymorphism*. Polymorphism allows you to use an object A as if it were an instance of another type B if A and B follow any one of these rules

- B is a class and A's type is a subclass of B
- B is an interface and A's type implements B

In your case, the first rule applies. Both `basicAccount` and `premiumAccount` are a subclass of `account`. Thus, **you can use your premium account and basic account objects as account objects!** So just ASSIGN the newly created object to the `account` field!

```
if(accountType.equals("Basic")){
    basicAccount account = new basicAccount();
    this.account = account; // This works! Don't worry!
}
else if(accountType.equals("Premium")){
    premiumAccount account = new premiumAccount();
    this.account = account;
}
```

A side effect, though, is that after using `basicAccount` and `premiumAccount` objects as `account`s, you cannot access the methods of `basicAccount` and `premiumAccount` by directly accessing `this.account`.

If you *really* want to do so, try this method:

Say you have a `doStuff` method defined in `basicAccount` and you want to call it:

```
this.account.doStuff();
```

That does not work because `this.account` is of type `account` and `account` does not define a method called `doStuff`.

What you need to do is check whether the `account` field is of type `basicAccount`:

```
if (this.account instanceof basicAccount)
```

In the if statement, cast `this.account` to `basicAccount` and call the method:

```
((basicAccount)this.account).doStuff();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would probably do it:

```
public class UserClass{
    Account account;

    public UserClass(String accountType){
         if(accountType.equals("Basic"){
              this.account = new basicAccount();
         } else {
              this.account = new premiumAccount();
         {
    }
}
```